# Input to Javascript from file via php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a setup where I want to send the results of a python script asynchronously to a webpage. I currently have a HTML page setup, with a Javascript file that deals with the information dynamically.

However, I don't really understand how to get the Javascript to interact with Server-side files, seeing as its done through PHP. What do I do to set up a php file that takes the input from a text file (generated every x seconds from the python script), and sends it to the Javascript?

Comment: what you are describing sounds like you want the server to push data to the browser, rather than the browser periodically requesting data from the server, is this your intent?

Comment: Yeah, that would be it exactly.

Comment: I would look into sockets if I were you. I know it may be a lot to begin with, but sockets are really helpful! It allows your server (Python in this case) to send something to the website (the client viewing the website). You can then display that data or handle it however you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to create iframe that will refresh every x seconds that points to that genereted file. Not sure if this will work in your situation.

```
<iframe id="genFile" src="link/to/genFile.txt"></iframe>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {   
        setInterval(function () {  
            document.getElementById('genFile').contentWindow.location.reload(true);
        }, 3000);
    } 
</script>
```

More complicated way is to use server side php script that will read that generated file content and setting up ajax requests to get script output every few seconds. This is better if you need to process this file between reading and outputting or when file is out of public scope.

Comment: This is actually perfect, I had no idea you could reload iframes like that. Cheers! Gonna just test it first before I accept it as the answer